# How to add a namespace using the new dotnet 6 template?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I don't want to revert to a dotnet 5 in order to have the usual class in Program.cs. Instead, I just want to add namespaces that goes *outside* the main class. Since now the class template isn't visible anymore, what would be the right way to add those additional namespaces?

Comment: Just type them in as you would previously. `namespace Foo { public class Bar { } }`

Answer (score 1):

Adding namespaces outside top-level statements is not supported.

1. [Top-level statements are implicitly in the global namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#global-namespace)
2. Top-level statements are specifically [not allowed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2021/LDM-2021-02-10.md#namespace-directives-in-top-level-programs) in combination with [file-scoped namespace declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#file-scoped-namespace-declaration) (introduced in C# 10 supported by .NET 6).

> we should disallow this combination. There's a couple reasons for this:
>
> ...
>
> Users might expect to be able to put a namespace before those
> top-level statements and change the namespace the implicit Main is
> generated into.